# 74190 counter problem

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, counter, ripple-counter

So, I got my 74190 counter shows number like this
 9-8-7-6-5-4-3-2-1-0-5-4-3-2-1-0-5-4-3-2-1-0-5-4-3-2-1-0 and so on.

My questions:

1. What can I do to change the output count down into 5-4-3-2-1-0-5-4-3-2-1-0 and so on?
2. When it changes 0 into 5 it moves so fast. How could I fix this one?

[image]

Comment: the output of U8A is short-circuited by the switch S3.  move the switch into the input circuit of U8A.

Comment: the schematic could be improved by simplifying the ground net so that ground wires do not cross other ground wires.

Comment: i dont know about how to move switch into the input circuit of u8A because it causes error on my circuit :(

Answer (score 1):

You cannot predict the initial state of the counter.

You must make a reset circuit that brings the counter to a known state at powerup.

Replace U8A with a NOR gate with one pin to an RC reset circuit or you can use a spare OR gate with U8A to make a NOR gate:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8vr7i.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

On powerup the capacitor will drag the second input to "1" for a short time forcing a a counter load. This will make the counter start from 5.

From the additional comment I understand that the technology used is really LS which has an 1 mA input current, I thought it was just the schematic.

A fix is to use a negative reset like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcjkd1.png)</sup>

R can be higher that 2k2 since the input high current is of uA order and also the capacitor if the reset does not work properly

Comment: But, it makes counter goes from 5-4-3-2-1-0-9-8-7-6-5-4-3-2-1-0-9-8-7-6-5-4-3-2-1-0-9-8-7 so on :(

Comment: How can be possible ? With the reset input to '0' it should act as an inverter as in the original schematic. Are you sure you wired the MAX/MIN output to the gate?

Comment: @EvangelinaTessiaP You actually use the old 74LS version , not 74HC or 74HCT version?

Comment: Yes. I use the old 74LS version

Comment: @EvangelinaTessiaP Oh, I didn't know that are still used, the LS have a higher input current that make the voltage on R to be higher than input low level. You should use a negative reset, i will update my answer right away

Comment: @EvangelinaTessiaP Did it worked?

Comment: well sorry for not informing you. I'm using ic 74169 instead if ic 74190. Because it works well and more easier than ic 74190. Thank you for your help.